# Add-in for multiple versions

Tags: visual-studio

I'm playing around with add-ins and I've noticed the following. VS2010 add-ins cannot be used with VS2008 (error when trying to load it), but VS2008 add-ins can be used with VS2010, by changing the value of `<Version>9.0</Version>` to `<Version>10.0</Version>`.

When the code for both VS2008 and VS2010 is the same, can a VS2008 add-in be used in VS2010 like described above? Or should two separate projects be maintained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the code for both VS2008 and VS2010 is the same, can a VS2008
>   add-in be used in VS2010 like described above?

Yes. For example, our [VSdocman add-in](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) is compiled in VS 2005 and it works fine in VS 2005, 2008 and 2010. You only need to create separate .addin file for each VS version during installation.